# How to set an checkbox in the Android toolbar navigation icon?

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, android-checkbox

I'm trying to set a checkbox in the toolbar's navigation icon like in the Lollipop gallery:

[image]

I know you can change with an image drawable like this:

```
mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(iconRes);
```

But how can i change the navigation icon to a checkbox? I tried to use a custom layout, but didn't worked:

checkbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and in the activity:

```
mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.layout.checkbox);
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: You can put Checkbox as a child layout inside your Toolbar layout in xml.

Comment: If i put the Checkbox as a child inside the Toolbar layout, the checkbox is in the right side of the title. I want the checkbox to be in the left side of the title.

Comment: You don't have to use default title `TextView`. You can add your own TextView on the right side of Checkbox for setting title.

Comment: @LeonardoCampanha what you want to achieve ? What final outcome of checkbox you want ?

Comment: It worked @Sharj, i created my own title and checkbox in my toolbar xml and removed the original ones. It worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the original navigation icon and the toolbar title, replacing it in the toolbar.xml with my own checkbox and title.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use a drawable resource id with setNavigationIcon.  You can't put a layout in there.

Comment: So to insert a checkbox in the navigationIcon it has to be 2 drawable images?

Comment: You can certainly put a single image in there, or perhaps a layer list drawable in there that draws two bitmaps, if that's what you need.  But you won't be able to get a functioning checkbox widget in there without doing a lot of custom work.